# How to use React with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, reactjs

I wanted to tryout React and started following the tutorial [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)
Took the Internet template, added the required script references in _Layout.cshtml and placed the following script in About.cshtml.

This code with the '@' char is giving trouble:

```
<script type="text/jsx">
  /**
   * @jsx React.DOM
   */
  // The above declaration must remain intact at the top of the script.
  // Your code here
</script>
```

MVC says:

> The name 'jsx' does not exist in the current context

Please provide some pointers

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried putting the script references in About.cshtml too?

Comment: Yup, same message there too.

Comment: Do you have enclosed this tag after reference the React script ?, Better to see and tried this demo https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/examples

Comment: Gupta, those are all for Js MVC frameworks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've just released [ReactJS.NET](http://reactjs.net/) which lets you easily compile JSX to JavaScript. With ReactJS.NET, you can put your code into a .jsx file (say `/Scripts/HelloWorld.jsx`) and then reference it via a script tag:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/HelloWorld.jsx")"></script>
```

Additionally, *ASP.NET Bundling and Minification* and *Cassette* are both supported.

---

*Original answer (pre 4th April 2014):*

You need to escape the `@` by writing it twice:

```
<script type="text/jsx">
  /**
   * @@jsx React.DOM
   */
  // The above declaration must remain intact at the top of the script.
  // Your code here
</script>
```

I'm currently working on some stuff to make it easier to use React from ASP.NET, which should be coming out very soon. This includes server-side compilation of JSX (both on the fly and via ASP.NET minification and combination) and optional server-side rendering of React components. Stay tuned!

Comment: Hey, it looks like I can't use the React or ReactInitJavaScript HTML helpers in my Razor views... I've tried following several StackOverflow and other posts and finally ended up posting my own. Can you take a gander and see if you can give your two cents? I was able to follow the CommentBox tutorial RIGHT up to the last optimization challenge. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look my project, a starter template for using React in .NET.

https://github.com/pauldotknopf/react-dot-net

This project solves many issues that are present in the other projects (NodeServices and ReactJS.NET), including truely isomorphic applications with matching server/client routing.